# calling on a method PresentPerson() from another class Person in a button click event

Tags: c#, visual-studio

so i have a simple web application which allows a user to input name, age, date, gender and telephone number

i am using a constructer to build a person called p

i am then trying to present the person using PresentPerson() method and assign the return string to a label

can you help me? i have an error with PresentPerson and im having trouble figuring it out, the coffee doesn't seem to be working

[application web form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxI5F.png)

[my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YIx4a.png)

My web page code:

```
public partial class _Default : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Person p = new Person(Convert.ToInt32(DropDownList1.SelectedValue), TextBox1.Text, Calendar1.SelectedDate, Convert.ToInt32(TextBox2.Text), DropDownList2.Text);
        string s = PresentPerson();

        Label2.Text = "" + s;

    }

}
```

My Person.cs code:

```
public class Person
{
    int age;
    string name;
    int telNo;
    string gender;
    DateTime dateOfBirth;

    public int Age { get => age; set => age = value; }
    public string Name { get => name; set => name = value; }
    public int TelNo { get => telNo; set => telNo = value; }
    public string Gender { get => gender; set => gender = value; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get => dateOfBirth; set => dateOfBirth = value; }

    public Person(int age, string name, DateTime dateOfBirth, int telNo, string gender)
    {
        this.age = age;
        this.name = name;
        this.DateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
        this.telNo = telNo;
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public string PresentPerson()
    {
        //PresentPerson();
        string s = "";
        s = name + ", age: " + age + ", telephone number: " + telNo + ", gender: " + gender + ", date of birth: " + DateOfBirth;

        return s;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call PresentPerson() on the object p.
So p.PresentPerson() will return the information.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Person p = new Person(Convert.ToInt32(DropDownList1.SelectedValue), TextBox1.Text, Calendar1.SelectedDate, Convert.ToInt32(TextBox2.Text), DropDownList2.Text);
    Label2.Text = p.PresentPerson();
}
```

Comment: ahh p.PresentPerson()! i will give it a go